# syslog-ng logs storing with hostname year date

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, mikrotik, syslog-ng

I have syslog-ng on Ubuntu 12.4 to store mikrotik router logs. At a moment its working fine and log gets stored in a file i set. 
Howto add store logs in a file/folder according to source IP so that each log file name may contain month year as well auto. My current config is as follows.

```
# Accept connection on UDP
source s_net { udp (); };
# Add Filter to add our mikrotik
filter f_mikrotik { host( "10.0.0.1" ); };
# Add destination file where logs will be stored
destination df_mikrotik { file("/var/log/mikrotik/mikrotik.log"); };
log { source ( s_net ); filter( f_mikrotik ); destination ( df_mikrotik ); };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use macros in your destination path or filename, for example: 
`file("/var/log/${YEAR}.${MONTH}.${DAY}/messages"`

For details, see [the list of syslog-ng macros](https://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/reference-macros.html)

Comment: Ok now syslog is making files by year/date, bu tthe problem is that when logrotate runs, it compress the file with same name with zero byte.
Example:
`-rw-r----- 1 root     adm     0 Jun 18 00:10 mikrotik.2016.06.16.log
-rw-r----- 1 root     adm  210K Jun 16 23:59 mikrotik.2016.06.16.log.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root     adm     0 Jun 18 00:10 mikrotik.2016.06.17.log
-rw-r----- 1 root     adm  580K Jun 17 23:59 mikrotik.2016.06.17.log.1.gz
-rw-r----- 1 root     adm     0 Jun 19 00:02 mikrotik.2016.06.18.log
-rw-r----- 1 root     adm  852K Jun 18 23:59 mikrotik.2016.06.18.log.1.gz`

Comment: I have following syslog-ng config for logrotate
`root@ubuntu:/var/log/mikrotik# cat /etc/logrotate.d/syslog-ng

/var/log/mikrotik/*.log {
        daily
        rotate 90
        missingok
        compress
        notifempty
        missingok
#       invoke-rc.d syslog-ng reload > /dev/null
        sharedscripts
        /etc/init.d/syslog-ng restart
        endscript
}`